# PubNub - Is there a way to find Channel Groups that contain a channel?

Tags: channel, pubnub

Is there any way other than getting all Channel Groups and checking each one individually?  I am wanting to go through and have the server remove the channel from all of the Channel Groups who contain that channel.

I have the client unsubscribing as it should, but in the event that it does not unsubscribe properly (browser crash/loss of connection/etc).  I know using presence and detecting leave/timeout is probably the best way to handle this.  But, it is just not something we can do in this first implementation.

Comment: There isn't an API to do this at this time but I will report back if there is anything on the roadmap to make this available.

Comment: It's not necessarily a solution that will work for all, but our system is basically set chat operators who answer incoming chats.  The operators have a lot of channels they need to subscribe to for different interactions within the system.  I just named the channel groups with similar information as the uuid for the operator.  I am then able to do a HereNow on the channel needing removed and see all the channel groups (operator uuids) who are chatting or listening in on the chat.  I can then easily remove the channel from those groups.

Comment: Yeah, that's clever - great idea.